# How to change display of "tab character" on PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I want to know setting of changing display of "tab character" on PhpStorm.

PhpStorm displays tab character like "--->". 
I want to change on "Colors & Fonts" of it. ( like "--->")

Doesn't it exist?

Comment: Search for `whitespace`

Comment: Thanks for replying. But I want to change "Collors & Fonts" of "tab character". It's not to change from "tab character" to "whitespace".

Comment: "whitespace" is the actual word/term that describes "tab character"

Comment: I see. Thanks. So, I should rewrite that [ It's not to change from "tab character" to "space character" ], should not I ?

Comment: .. ?? Sorry, but I do not understand what you want here.

Comment: PhpStorm displays tab character like "--->". I want to change on "Colors & Fonts" of it. ( like "--->")

Comment: The "Settings" screen has search box on the top left corner. Is it really so difficult to type `whitespace` there and go through few results to find the one needed? http://postimg.org/image/m8x6799cp/

Comment: Oh! I did it. Thank you! The color of tab character was changed by changing Background color of 'Whitespaces'! It (like "--->") was a Background not Foreground!

Answer (score 8):

For anyone else not interested in doing a manual search (the search box in 10.0.3 didn't locate the option for me), it's under editor -> colors & fonts -> general -> text -> whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

The color of tab character was changed by changing Background color of 'Whitespaces'!

It (like "--->") was a Background not Foreground!

Thanks to LazyOne.